# How to disable breakpoints in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, breakpoints

it's my first time working with bootstrap. I'm using it for an accordeon footer for the mobile breakpoint. The problem now is that bootstrap is setting other breakpoints I don't want for the rest of my design. How can I disable this? The file that does this is called "grid.less". I only use bootstrap to make the footer work, really nothing else. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: It's all [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints). But simply not using `-sm-`, `-lg-`, etc... classes should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override Bootstrap's style with your own style. Firstly you have to put the link of your style bellow the Bootstrap's link like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
```

Secondly you have to find the styles you want to override, possibly with dev tools. For example:

From grid.scss:

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.container {
    max-width: 960px;
}
```

Your style:

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.container {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

and so on.